# Creating interactive window .bat file to copy development file into production folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, dos

Need expert to help me to do simple window .bat file to copy files/folder into different specific folder

```
ProjectDevFolder
    /module1
        /module1-1
        /module1-2
    /module2
        /module2-1
            /module2-1-1
                /module2-1-1-1
        /module2-2
    /images
    /css
    /jquery
    /classes
    .jspfile1
    .jspfile2
    .jspfile3
    .jspfile4
```

**To test destination**

```
wwwFolder
    /module1
        /module1-1
        /module1-2
    /module2
        /module2-1
            /module2-1-1
                /module2-1-1-1
        /module2-2
    /images
    /css
    /jquery
    /classes
    .jspfile1
    .jspfile2
    .jspfile3
    .jspfile4
```

Example of window command prompt

```
C:\DeployScript.bat
To copy : css module2-1-1-1 jquery *(user can input multiple value with any seperator eg:space is the seperator)*
 - Status deploy css  -done
 - Status deploy module2-1-1-1  -done
 - Status deploy jquery  -done

To copy :   *(Next command)*
```

Thank you

Comment: Just as an aside: theoretically, some subfolders might have identical names, like e.g. `Documentation` in `Employees` and in `Customers`. Your example of user input doesn't seem to let you tell one `Documentation` folder from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy all files and subdirectories (including empty ones) from `sourceDir` to `targetDir`.

```
XCOPY /S /E /I sourceDir targetDir
```

`targetDir` does not need to exist. `XCOPY` will create it if need be.
To exclude empty directories, leave out the `/e`.

To exclude files, create a text file containing the names of the files to exclude, and use this command:

```
XCOPY /S /E /I /EXCLUDE:files.txt sourceDir targetDir
```

To learn more about `xcopy`, type `XCOPY /?` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be split into at least two problems:

- Split user input
- Copy directories

  - Find directories recursively (module2-1-1-1)

Some questions to clarify:

- How to enter the destination root directory
- What happens if a destination folder (or a subfolder there of) exists already?

---

Here are some pointers for those two problems:

- Split user input: [How to split a string in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file)
- Recursion in batch: [Windows Batch File Looping Through Directories to Process Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397674/windows-batch-file-looping-through-directories-to-process-files) (to adapt)

Comment: I plan to hard code the destination in the batch file eg :  css ==> destination/Folder/css , images to image destination, default source is to home destination folder...

If the folder does not exists, how can we create automatically recursively for any children folder