# Batch For loop array

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Okay so here is what I have.

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:begin
set /a M=0
set /a number=0
set /p Input=You: 
echo %Input% >> UIS
for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in ("%Input%") do (
    set /a M+=1
    set i!M!=%%i
)
del UIS 1>nul 2>nul
:loop
set /a number+=1
set invar=!i%number%!
echo %invar%
pause > nul
goto loop
```

Say, for example, the Input string was "Lol this is my input string"
I want the for loop to set i!M! where M = 1 to "Lol", where M = 2 i!M! is "this" and where M = 3 i!M! is "is" and so on. Now, of course, this can't go on forever, so even if I have to stop when M = 25 or something, and say the string was only 23 words long. Then when M = 24 and 25 then i!M! is simply null or undefined.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Tell us what's not working about the script.

Comment: Well as it is it only reads the first word from the string, and will not set the value of M past 1.

Answer (score 1):

`for /f` reads line by line, not word by word.

Here's an answer proposed at [How to split a string in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file) and modified for your situation:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Set a string with an arbitrary number of substrings separated by semi colons
set teststring=Lol this is my input string
set M=0

REM Do something with each substring
:stringLOOP
    REM Stop when the string is empty
    if "!teststring!" EQU "" goto displayloop

    for /f "delims= " %%a in ("!teststring!") do set substring=%%a

    set /a M+=1
    set i!M!=!substring!

    REM Now strip off the leading substring
    :striploop
        set stripchar=!teststring:~0,1!
        set teststring=!teststring:~1!

        if "!teststring!" EQU "" goto stringloop

        if "!stripchar!" NEQ " " goto striploop

        goto stringloop

:displayloop
set /a number+=1
set invar=!i%number%!
echo %invar%
pause > nul
goto displayloop

endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

`for /F` command divide a line in a *definite* number of tokens that must be processed at once via different replaceable parameters  (%%i, %%j, etc). Plain `for` command divide a line in an *undefined* number of words (separated by space, comma, semicolon or equal-sign) that are processed one by one in an iterative loop. This way, you just need to change this for:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in ("%Input%") do (
```

by this one:

```
for %%i in (%Input%) do (
```

PS - I suggest you to write  the array in the standard form, enclosing the subscript in square brackets; it is clearer this way:

```
set i[!M!]=%%i
```

or

```
set invar=!i[%number%]!
```