# Windows commandline: get Lines from text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

With command line in Windows, I have a game score system which goes on. It saves the scores into a text file by using the code:

```
if %LS_RegioLex_EndSave%==1 (echo Single Player Latest Score 1 - RegioLex: %S_REGIOLEX_SCORE% > LostChamberSinglePlayerRegioLexSCORE01.txt)
```

How do I do the opposite and get the saved scores from the text file and display them?

Comment: `type LostChamberSinglePlayerRegioLexSCORE01.txt`. If that isn't what you need, please [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you load the .txt to a string, you can split a string as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file), or as shown [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.SplitString)

Any reason you're tied to batch? Powershell makes it a cakewalk with [Import-CSV](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the data on the first line.

```
set /p "var="<"LostChamberSinglePlayerRegioLexSCORE01.txt"
echo "%var%"
```