# win32 shell scripting - define set of strings and loop over it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this 'win32 shell scipt' (?):

```
FOR %%filename IN (*.txt) DO (
...
)
```

I would like to replace the set (*.txt) with a set of strings defined as variable at the beginning of the script. Could someone please point me to the appropriate documentation of 'win32 shell scipt' or even better provide some 'code'?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look.

Comment: This helped thanks. Do you know how to use strings that contain spaces?

Comment: Provide some of the strings in your question, to help us provide working code.

Comment: Just use a different delimiter (`delims` option in `FOR`). You may use, for example, a comma or a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear the requirements, but, as requested, some code

```
@echo off
  setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

  :: the normal strings
  set "var1=one"
  set "var2=this is a test"
  set "var3=two"

  :: a set of files
  set "var4=*.cmd"

  for %%a in ("%var1%" "%var2%" "%var3%" "%var4%") do echo %%a, %%~a
```

And, of course, you should see `for /?`