# break a string in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I need to split a string that come from a variable and, according to another variable, print the result, something like the following example
    set "DIRECTORY=c:\test1;c:\test2"

```
set "PROG=TEST1"
REM "PROG=TEST2"

for /f "tokens=* delims=;" %%f in ("%DIRECTORY%") do (
if "%PROG%" == "TEST1"
    echo ...... c:\test1
) else (
    echo ...... c:\test2
)
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Almost ...the answer to that post are based by the tokens ...what I need is like a loop, independent of the tokens

Comment: You're right, sorry, it is a duplicated ...thank you

Comment: No problem, I wasn't sure to begin with, but there are so many solutions in the other question that it looked like one of them would hit the mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem: `tokens=*` means "take the complete line", so `delims=;` has no effect.

Use this syntax instead:

```
for %%f in (%directory%) do echo %%f
```

The problem here is: you can not set any delimitors, it takes "standard" delimitors: space, comma, tab,`;`

So you have to enclose every token into doublequotes. Do do so, enclose the first string into doublequotes and replace every delimiter by `","`. So `c:\test1;c:\test2` becomes `"c:\test1","c:\test2"`, what can be parsed easily. (the `~`in `%%~f` removes the surrounding doublequotes)

```
for %%f in ("%directory:;=","%") do @echo %%~f
```

Comment: Just commenting that `tokens=*` actually means "take the complete line except remove any leading spaces" and `"delims="` means "take the complete line" which is not quite the context you mean, but it's true all the same.

Comment: @foxidrive I always considered `"tokens=*"` and `"delims="` to be interchangable.  Another prove that "I know" is not the same as "It's a fact" ^^ Thanks for that info.