# How Can I Split String With CMD

Tags: string, windows, cmd, split

I have a little question.
ı want string split with cmd.
Example :

```
emre;bahadir;131213034;computer
```

i want to

```
var1=emre 
var2=bahadir 
var3=131213034 
var4=computer
```

please help me ! :)

Comment: Do you want to do this in windows command prompt? Is it given that there won't be more than 4 tokens? If not, it should be stored in an array.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: Did ashutosh's link not help you? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: This should be closed, there is no evidence of self-starting and it has been answered previously.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regular `FOR` loop

```
@Echo OFF 

Set "str=emre;bahadir;131213034;computer"

For %%_ In (%str%) DO (
    echo %%_
)

Pause&Exit /B 0
```

Answer (score 0):

basically the same as ElektroStudios' answer, but expanded with a counter to set the variables:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "str=emre;bahadir;131213034;computer"
set x=0
For %%a In (%str%) DO (
  set /a x+=1
  set "var!x!=%%a"
)
set var
```