# Extract part of a path in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script with input say `/home/home1/home2/home3/`

I need to extract part of the file path say `/home2/home3`. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you specify which part of the string supplied you require?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested:

```
@echo off

set "p=/home/home1/home2/home3/"
set "p=%p:/=";"%"

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%a in ("%p%") do (
    if "%%~a" neq "" set "butlast=!last!"
    if "%%~a" neq "" set "last=%%~a"

)

echo %butlast%/%last%
```

Answer (score 0):

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/" %%a in ('echo /home/home1/home2/home3/') do @echo /%%b/%%c

tokens tells for how many variables to spit out & delims tells it what to split on. %%a is the first token, it will count out a through d because  it is told to generate 4.

you will likely have your path as a variable, you can just put it in place of the path in the example, but you may need to use delayed expansion