# How to get name of the folder where jpg is in it?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a code to find jpg files and get a list of directory's name where files exists.
I have write a code that finds all folders my code is

```
For /r %%i in (.) do ( echo %%~nf >>list1.txt
)
For /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list1.txt) do ( echo %%~nxi >>list2.txt
)
```

And it saves a list of all subfolders but i want to get name of folder where file exists.

Comment: My language is batch

Comment: Never heard of batch.  Do you mean the Windows .bat files?

Comment: @Mhwmd  looks like it is possible. Did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-by-spaces-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: Yes it is .bat language

Comment: Just use the `FOR /R` to get the list of the jpg files.  It will give you the folder names and the file names at the same time.

Comment: This is now your 5th question on StackOverFlow and you have not accepted an answer to any of your questions.  If you do not understand how StackOverFlow works please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: `for /R %%I in (*.jpg) do echo %%~dpI.`? or `for /R %%I in (.) do if exist "%%~I\*.jpg" echo %%~fI`?

Comment: @Mhwmd please go back and accept answers to all your questions. That is how you give thanks on StackOverFlow!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not properly understand what you read when you do research. As an example.

```
For /r %%i in (.) do ( echo %%~nf >>list1.txt
```

tells me you have seen this `%%~nf` somewhere but did you try read up on what it does? You give a variable of `%%i` but you try and use `%%f` and you want the path (`%%~p`) but use the name (`%%~n`). If you actually ran the help from cmd `for /?` you would have had some great tips.

This:

```
For /r %%i in (*.jpg) do echo "%%~dpi" >>list1.txt
```

Would give drive and path to file, where this:

```
For /r %%i in (*.jpg) do echo "%%~pi" >>list1.txt
```

Would give just the path, while this:

```
For /r %%i in (*.jpg) do echo "%%~nxi" >>list1.txt
```

Would give the name and extention of the file and finally this:

```
For /r %%i in (*.jgp) do echo "%%~ni" >>list1.txt
```

Would give only the name of the file without extension.

So I challenge you to run help switches for your commands via cmd and I promise you, you will be astonished to see what you can learn from this.