# Batch command split character

Tags: batch-file

I need to split a string something like this; and try to get number

> "Record Count/CC_NUMBER = 123".

I tried to many ways but crashed different things.

The number can be bigger ( 4 digit or more ) or smaller

Thanks in already for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the line length can contain any number of words, then split by `=` and strip the whitespace, it will also not care if the `=` has spaces or not before and after:

```
@echo off
set "line=this can be any length Record Count/CC_NUMBER = 123"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ("%line%") do set "var=%%i"
echo %var: =%
```

Additionally as suggested by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) a similar but shorter approach to the above:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ("%line: =%") do echo %%i
```

If the line is with spaces and there the number is the 3rd token, as in your example:

```
@echo off
set "line=Record Count/CC_NUMBER = 123"
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ("%line%") do echo %%i
```

If the line does not contain spaces we split by the `=` instead:

```
@echo off
set "line=Record Count/CC_NUMBER=123"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ("%line%") do echo %%i
```

Comment: Another possible way (for this special usecase): `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ("%line: =%") do echo %%i`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. You made my day :)

Comment: @alidrsn. No problem, so what you need to do is consider which of these answers solved your problem then mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to use a standard [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)):

```cmd
set "STR=Record Count/CC_NUMBER = 123"
for %%I in (%STR%) do set "VAL=%%I"
echo/%VAL%
```

Every <kbd>SPACE</kbd> as well as the `=`-sign are treated as token separators, and every token is handled by the `for` loop, and the last iteration assigns the numeric value to the variable.

This may fail when the string contains any of these characters: `*`, `?`, `<`, `>`, `"`, `^`, `|`, `&`, `(`, `)`.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to split the input by space, and then print/echo the third token:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%G IN ("Record Count/CC_NUMBER = 123") DO echo %%G
```

See [How to split a string by spaces in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-by-spaces-in-a-windows-batch-file) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If the desired token is strict numerical (within the bounds of [INT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Long_integer)), you can use `set /a`, which ignores any spaces:

```
@echo off
set "line=this can be any length Record Count/CC_NUMBER = 123"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ("%line%") do set /a var=%%i
echo "%var%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using regex in powershell to extract a digit number from a string content from a `TestFile.txt`

```bat
@echo off & color 0A
Title Extract a Digit Number from String using Regex in Powershell
Set "InputFile=TestFile.txt"
Set psCmd="&{$content=Get-Content -Path '%InputFile%';[regex]$regex='\d+';$regex.Matches($content).value}"
Call :RunPS %psCmd% Number
Echo The Number extracted is N=%Number%
pause & Exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
:RunPS <PassPSCMD> <RetValue>
  for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`Powershell %1`) do set "%2=%%i"
Goto:eof
:: End of :RunPS function
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using the **`echo`** command, combine with **`cmd /u`** removing non numbers in string by using **`Find + FindSTR +regex`** in a loop **`For`**.

---

- Where all characters turn output like this: **U N I C O D E**
- Unicode output layout is mainly characterized by the space between them in **`cmd /u echo your string`**.
- When taking the output **characters one by one**, you don't have to **worry/working with the delimiter's**, the **`FindSTR`** and **`RegEx`** to get just **numbers** in this output process...

  ---

---

Use a **`For`** to loop one by one character for filter your string in **`U n i c o d e`** **`echo`** output and remove the spaces by **`Find / v " "`**, then apply another filter with **`FindSTR`** to get only **numbers** by adding **[regex](/questions/tagged/regex)** in **`FindSTR`** and save the incremented loop output to an variable.

---

**<kbd>`Loop output variable !_str! in unicode filter space and get numbers:`</kbd>**

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set "_str= Record Count/CC_NUMBER = 01234 "
for /f %%n in ('cmd /u /c echo="!_str!"^|find /v " "^|findstr [0-9]
')do echo=%%n

:: echo=%%n ==  one by one nunber character in loop output:
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------
:: echo=%%n == output !_str! reults == 0 
:: echo=%%n == output !_str! reults == 1 
:: echo=%%n == output !_str! reults == 2 
:: echo=%%n == output !_str! reults == 3 
:: echo=%%n == output !_str! reults == 4 
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Obs.: 1)**

---

> - Therefore, manipulating the output **one by one**, you can check whether the output character is a number and not, otherwise the present character in processing, nor will it be displayed, where is this capable possible to check/take any **numbers** occurs at **any position** in the **variable/string**, loop, so, there no need **worry/work with delimiters**.
>
>   ---

---

**Obs.: 2)**

---

> - This mechanical work's by using of the **`EnableDelayedExpansion`** in this cmd/bat process.
>
>   ---

---

---

**<kbd>`Loop output variable !_str! in Unicode incremented variable with numbers %%n:`</kbd>**

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

(set "_str=0R/ecord\-# ',? 1>|<2Count>/3$4]C{^5_6&7}NUMBER = *|8!9"
for /f %%n in ('cmd /u /c echo="!_str!"^|find /v " "^|findstr [0-9]
')do set "_l=!_l!%%~n") && echo=Numbers in this variable _str: !_l!

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: loop output !_str! reults == 0 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 0          
:: loop output !_str! reults == 1 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 01         
:: loop output !_str! reults == 2 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 012        
:: loop output !_str! reults == 3 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 0123       
:: loop output !_str! reults == 4 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 01234      
:: loop output !_str! reults == 5 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 012345     
:: loop output !_str! reults == 6 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 0123456    
:: loop output !_str! reults == 7 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 01234567   
:: loop output !_str! reults == 8 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 012345678  
:: loop output !_str! reults == 9 && set "_var=!_var!%%~n results == 0123456789 
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

[image]

---

> - **<kbd>`get all numbers 01234 from string independent of the delimiter`</kbd>**
>
>   ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

(set "_str= Record Count/CC_NUMBER = 01234 "
for /f %%n in ('cmd /u /c echo="!_str!"^|find /v " "^|findstr [0-9]
')do set "_l=!_l!%%~n") && echo=Numbers in this variable _str: !_l!

rem :: Code Results: Numbers in this variable _str: 01234
```

---

[image]

---

---

> - **<kbd>`To get all numbers from string in any position independent of the delimiter`</kbd>**

---

> - String: **`0R/ecord\-# ',? 1>|<2Count>/3$4]C{^5_6&7}NUMBER = *|8!9`**
> - Output: **`Numbers in this variable _str: 0123456789`**
>
>   ---

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

(set "_str=0R/ecord\-# ',? 1>|<2Count>/3$4]C{^5_6&7}NUMBER = *|8!9"
for /f %%n in ('cmd /u /c echo="!_str!"^|find /v " "^|findstr [0-9]
')do set "_l=!_l!%%~n") && echo=Numbers in this variable _str: !_l!
```

---

[image]

---