# How to split a string and get the nth substring in Windows Powershell command line?

Tags: powershell

[How to split a string by spaces in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-by-spaces-in-a-windows-batch-file) didn't work for me.

I issue a Windows command to list the session ID of the logged in user, like this

```
PS C:\> $id = (quser /server:'ServerName' | Where-Object { $_ -match 'User' })
PS C:\> echo $id
User         console       4  Active none    6/13/1023 9:00 AM
```

How can I get the session id "4" from the output? I tried

```
PS C:\> $id = (quser /server:'ServerName' | Where-Object { $_ -match 'User' }).split(' ')[2]
```

but `$id` is just a blank string.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With hard-coded

```
$id = 'User         console       4  Active none    6/13/1023 9:00 AM'
```

First, check all `split` syntax variants:

```
$id.Split
```

> ```
> OverloadDefinitions
> -------------------
> string[] Split(Params char[] separator)
> string[] Split(char[] separator, int count)
> string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)
> string[] Split(char[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)
> string[] Split(string[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)
> string[] Split(string[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)
> ```

Then, use

```
$id.Split(' ', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

> ```
> User
> console
> 4
> Active
> none
> 6/13/1023
> 9:00
> AM
> ```

Without additional parameters, `$id.Split(' ').Count` gives `26` while 
`$id.Split(' ', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries).Count` -> `8`

Answer (score 1):

A PowerShell-idiomatic solution is to use the ***unary* form of the [`-split`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)**, which behaves as follows:

- Leading and trailing whitespace is ignored.
- Any nonempty run of whitespace - no matter how long - is treated as a single separator.

```bash
$id = (-split (quser /server:'ServerName' | Where-Object { $_ -match 'jdoe' }))[2]
```

<sup>Note: You'll probably want to make the `-match` operation more robust, such as with `-match '\bjdoe\b`'</sup>

---

A simpler example:

```bash
-split '  one          two  three ' | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
```

Output (prints the resulting tokens enclosed in `[...]`):

```bash
[one]
[two]
[three]
```

---

Note that there are reasons to *generally* prefer the `-split` *operator* to the `.Split()` .NET string *method*, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, in Windows cmd, you can use the `FOR /F` command to split a string and get the nth token (substring). Below is an example:

Suppose you have the following string: "This is a test string" and you want to get the 3rd word (which is "a" in this case). You could do:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set str="This is a test string"
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ("%str%") do set nth_word=%%a
echo !nth_word!
```

In this script, `tokens=3` specifies to get the third word, `delims=` sets the delimiter to a space (which is the separator in this case), `%%a` is the variable that will hold the value of the third word, `"%str%"` is the string to split, `set nth_word=%%a` sets the value of `%%a` to the variable `nth_word`, and `echo !nth_word!` prints out the value of `nth_word`.

Comment: Thanks, but I tagged this as a `Powershell` question.